# SQL Query to find unique column value based on values from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table like this

[image]

Schema for this table and sample insert queries to build this table:

```
CREATE TABLE demotable (
    Id int,
    PrivilageId int,
    RoleId int    
);

insert into demotable values (1 ,40, 101)
insert into demotable values (2 ,12, 101)
insert into demotable values (3 ,40, 102)
insert into demotable values (4 ,40, 104)
insert into demotable values (5 ,12, 128)
insert into demotable values (6 ,40, 107)
insert into demotable values (7 ,17, 103)
insert into demotable values (8 ,17, 107)
insert into demotable values (9 ,15, 138)
insert into demotable values (10 ,15, 102)
insert into demotable values (11 ,17, 104)
insert into demotable values (12 ,12, 101)
```

As you can see If I want to see all the RoleIDs for Privilage ID 40, I can easily get that by this query.

```
select * from DemoTable where PrivilageID =  40
```

This gives me result of `101, 102, 104, 107`

But my requirement is opposite. I know that this particular combination `101, 102, 104, 107` has only one `PrivilageID` . I need a query where I can pass `101, 102, 104, 107` and I will get an output of `40`

What I tried is: I created intersect queries like this:

```
select PrivilageId from DemoTable where RoleID = 101
intersect
select PrivilageId from DemoTable where RoleID = 102
intersect
select PrivilageId from DemoTable where RoleID = 104
intersect
select PrivilageId from DemoTable where RoleID = 107
```

This works but is there any better way?

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server` or `MySQL` ?

Comment: SQL server. But any database will do. just need the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try `HAVING` with the condition aggregate function `COUNT` with `DISTINCT` condition.

We just need to add filter `RoleId` in `CASE WHEN` expression, and the count might equal as your `RoleId` number.

```
SELECT PrivilageId 
FROM DemoTable 
GROUP BY PrivilageId 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN RoleId IN (101, 102, 104, 107) THEN RoleId END) = 4
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=8d359da200ab8b00729cc1660806d6dd)

Comment: This works! accepted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of possible ways to do this. As example, you can use `HAVING` which has already been mentioned. Another option is using `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.privilageid FROM demotable d WHERE 
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM demotable WHERE roleid = 101 AND d.privilageid = privilageid) AND
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM demotable WHERE roleid = 102 AND d.privilageid = privilageid) AND
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM demotable WHERE roleid = 104 AND d.privilageid = privilageid) AND
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM demotable WHERE roleid = 107 AND d.privilageid = privilageid)
```